# VBA Multiple FreeFile Exports to CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv, text

I'm trying to use the Freefile to export to text files. The process is taking a worksheet with many columns and for each column, exporting it as text.

The problem I've been having is getting the error 55 code "file is already open".

Because I want the column range as the input to be of a variable length, I don't know for certain how many freefile commands I would need.

```
For j = intColumOffsett + 1 To intLastColumn

strDate = wkSource.Cells(1, j).Value

strNewFile = strDirectory & strDate & " New.csv"


For i = 1 To intLastRow
    strTarget = strTarget & wkSource.Cells(i, 1).Value & ","
    strTarget = strTarget & wkSource.Cells(i, 2).Value & ","
    strTarget = strTarget & wkSource.Cells(i, 3).Value & ","
    strTarget = strTarget & strDate & ","
    strTarget = strTarget & wkSource.Cells(i, j).Value

' It's this this section I'm not sure about \/ 
'Set strNewFile = Nothing
'Stop
iF1 = FreeFile(j)
'Close #iF1

On Error GoTo Error:
    Open strNewFile For Output As #iF1
         Print #iF1, strTarget
        Debug.Print strTarget
    strTarget = ""
Error:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)

Next i
Close #iF1
Next j
```

How can I avoid these errors will exporting as many new CSV's as I needed depending on the unknown number of columns from the source....?????

Comment: You don't close the file in the inner loop, so it never gets changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FreeFile` will generate a new file number each time you call it.

But in your code, you were calling it for each row.

And you error handling wasn't appropriate, so I added a sub to show how you should use! ;)

```
    Sub MultiFreeFiles()
    '''...

    For j = intColumOffsett + 1 To intLastColumn
        strDate = wkSource.Cells(1, j).Value
        strNewFile = strDirectory & strDate & " New.csv"

        iF1 = FreeFile

        On Error GoTo Error:
        Open strNewFile For Output As #iF1

        For i = 1 To intLastRow
            strTarget = vbNullString
            With wkSource
                strTarget = strTarget & .Cells(i, 1).Value & ","
                strTarget = strTarget & .Cells(i, 2).Value & ","
                strTarget = strTarget & .Cells(i, 3).Value & ","
                strTarget = strTarget & strDate & ","
                strTarget = strTarget & .Cells(i, j).Value
            End With 'wkSource

            Debug.Print strTarget

            Print #iF1, strTarget
        Next i
        Close #iF1
    Next j
    '''...


    Exit Sub
Error:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
    Resume

    End Sub
```

Comment: WOW, thanks big..... is the main thing I had wrong a resume statement?   or maybe the "iF1 = FreeFile" had to be one more loop out.

Comment: @The_BMan : Both `FreeFile` and `Open ...` needed to be outside of the loop and as for the error handling it's just that it was in the middle of your code (which can be ok for certain uses if it's handled properly), but yours would have been triggered for each row of each column even if there wasn't any error! ;)